# outlook anchor tag underline doesn't work

Tags: html, css, outlook, anchor, html-email

i'm going to be crazy about this. I'm trying to remove the underline inside my anchor tags in my page.
I've tried all the solutions around the web but non of them is works.

This is the code that i'm using for tests. I've tried putting !important to text-decoration, i've tried to but a conditional style just for outlook, I tried to put the text in the a tag inside a span, but none of them still works.
Seeing the html in the ooutlook app, it does displays correctly, but when i'm trying to see it on the outlook from browser, it doesn't work, i still see the underlined text.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>{0}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
   <span>
     <a href="http://www.w3.com" style="text-decoration: none">TEST</a>
   </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Someone that knows how to avoid that?

Comment: Try emptying cache and hard reload. As your code is working fine and there is no underline in the text:
JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/rgauj8bo/

Comment: @AhmadHabib this works in a normale browser, but i'm talking about display that on an email, like outlook. I cant' figured out how to remove the underline from the anchor tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-decoration:none` is pretty [well supported in most email clients](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-text-decoration/). And I ran [a test of your code in Email on Acid](https://app.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/E5nXUdY1Jqs7A4aegqA7DEQBz1K7gUwoIvCFFV7OyTtYb/list), and I'm not seeing any problem with it.

Could you maybe give more details like: how you're sending your HTML email and which version of Outlook are using exactly.

Comment: i'm sending the html from outlook desktop app. Then i m trying to see it on https://outlook.office.com/ . The desktop app version is Microsoft Outlook 365 MSO (16.0...)  and evne if in your lEmailOnAcid Link displays well, i still have that problem, that's why i can't udnerstand what is happening

Answer (score 0):

it maybe text-decoration property of CSS where as override  in your code plz check of your code. if it is not working then write the property of CSS text-decoration: underline !important

Comment: using text-decoration: underline !important, leave the underline under the text...instead adding text-decoration: none !important doesn't resolve the problem